# Modern words to compliment a beautiful woman/girl beauty

Tags: word-choice, word-requests

I am looking for **two** **modern** Chinese words to compliment a beautiful girl. Here are what I have found: 美女，宝贝，女神。are there any thing else?

The other words that I can think of, but doesn't really works are: 如花, 佳麗, 天仙, 淑女, 仙子. because you would not say this when you see a beauty: hey, 如花，吃饭没有？

And also, why are there so many 4-words Chinese phrases to describe a beauty? To name a few: 閉月羞花 沉魚落雁 傾國傾城 國色天香 天生麗質 清麗脫俗 花容月貌 明眸皓齒  美艷絕世........................................

Are Chinese scholars really into hot and cute chicks?

Comment: 宝贝：bkrs：(5) [darling]∶对亲爱者的昵称。 心爱的人, 多用于小孩儿

Comment: *to compliment a beautiful girl* You meant to her face? Chinese don't usually do that.

Comment: *why are there so many 4-words Chinese phrases to describe a beauty*  Chinese use four characters phrases a lot in general, it feels more idiomatic, and some are actual idioms.

Comment: Modern words? Try 萌妹纸 or even 傻逼娃娃. That's what kids use these days…

Comment: re: comment #2: in TV dramas such ＂compliments＂ are not uncommon，especially when old friends meet again and when expressed by females toward other females，在好多电视剧中尤其老朋友再次见面的时候，这样称赞（恭维 ）并非罕见，再说两位女性之间从来没有问题。

Comment: ＠user6065 in ＂老朋友再次见面的时候＂ the subject 老朋友 must be considered of definite reference, i.e. the meaning is "when the old friends meet again", which is not the intended meaning, thus the sentence may be considered wrong (or translatese), proposed correction:  put 有 in front：有（某些）老朋友再次见面的时候

Answer (score 1):

美女 is the safest choice.

宝贝 is used to call someone (boy or girl) who's in a romantic relationship with you, or you call a baby girl (usually aged < 10) 宝贝.

女神 nowadays has some negative meanings and is not recommended.

Other similar choices are 小美女，靓妹.

An example in wechat:
[image: real world example]

Answer (score 1):

Better to avoid 如花, because most Chinese may think of this 如花 from Stephen Chow's movies.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**大美人** (great beauty)

Example sentences:

- 她是一個不折不扣的**大美人** ( She is an authentic great beauty)
- **大美人**鄺美雲的花名是鄺美人 (Great beauty Cally Kwong's nickname is Beauty Kwong)
- 妳這種**大美人**當然不怕沒男人追求 (Great beauty like you, of course you don't have to worry about no one courting you)

It is kind of a honoring term.

Comment: I am asking for 2 words, not 3.

Comment: you should had written:  "two characters word" then, 大美人 is made up of two words, 大(great) 美人(beauty)